# Чтение полей структуры с консоли при выводе обратно в консоль выдает мусор

Tags: c++, ввод

Мне надо создавать новые объекты, заполняя их поля данными с консоли. Объект содержит такие поля:

```
struct object
{
    std::string name;
    std::string type;
    double x;
    double y;
    std::time_t time;

    double distance() const
    {
        // Расстояние от точки (0, 0) до объекта
        return std::sqrt(
            std::pow(x, 2) + std::pow(y, 2)
        );
    }
};
```

Читаю и вывожу объекты в консоль так:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const object& o)
{
    os << "name: " << o.name
        << " type: " << o.type
        << " x: " << o.x
        << " y: " << o.y
        << " time: " << ctime(&o.time);

    return os;
}

inline object operator >> (std::istream& is, object& o)
{
    object obj;

    std::cout << "Enter name: ";
    is >> obj.name;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Enter x coordinate: ";
    is >> obj.x;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Enter y coordinate: ";
    is >> obj.y;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Enter type: ";
    is >> obj.type;
    obj.time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    return obj;
}
```

Проблема в том, что при чтении, а потом выведении объекта выводится мусор или нулевые значения:

```
Enter object data: 
Enter name, x coordinate, y coordinate and type: ttt 12.5 12.5 rrr
view::update() called
Added object: name:  type:  x: 0 y: 0 time: Thu Jan  1 03:00:00 1970
```

Почему так? Дата создания тоже странная - начало эпохи. Как сохранить в объекте текущую дату (это время создания объекта)?

Добавил минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

struct object
{
    std::string name;
    std::string type;
    double x;
    double y;
    std::time_t time;

    double distance() const
    {
        // Расстояние от точки (0, 0) до объекта
        return std::sqrt(
            std::pow(x, 2) + std::pow(y, 2)
        );
    }
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const object& o)
{
    os << "name: " << o.name
        << " type: " << o.type
        << " x: " << o.x
        << " y: " << o.y
        << " time: " << ctime(&o.time);

    return os;
}

inline object operator >> (std::istream& is, object& o)
{
    object obj;

    std::cout << "Enter name, x coordinate, y coordinate and type: ";
    is >> obj.name >>
            obj.x >>
            obj.y >>
            obj.type;

    obj.time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    object obj;

    std::cin >> obj;

    std::cout << obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы что-то не то пишете. У вас вводятся в коде поля по одному, в примере — в одну строку. Кода самого запроса нет. Вдруг у вас есть два запроса типа `>>`, сначала числа, а потом слова? По вашим "отрывкам из обрывков" идентифицировать проблему можно только вероятностно (один вариант я уже подсказал). Задайте вопрос нормально...

Comment: дайте [example]

Comment: @n1tr0xs Да вроде человек с более чем 2000 репутацией должен уметь задавать вопросы :)

Comment: Добавил минимальный воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Пожалейте процессор: `double distance() const { return std::hypot(x,y); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Итак, что мы видим?

```
inline object operator >> (std::istream& is, object& o)
{
    object obj;

    ... Далее чтение obj, не o

    return obj;
}
```

Т.е. считанное только возвращается, но никакого отношения к передаваемому в оператор аргументу не имеет...

Тогда уж надо было писать хотя бы

```
obj = std::cin >> obj;
```

А так вы все введенное благополучно игнорируете...

Кстати, обычно операторы `>>` имеют вид

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, object& o)
```

чтобы можно было создавать цепочки

```
cin >> a >> b ...
```

Словом, следующий код

```
inline  std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, object& obj)
{
    std::cout << "Enter name, x coordinate, y coordinate and type: ";
    is >> obj.name >>
            obj.x >>
            obj.y >>
            obj.type;

    obj.time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    return is;
}
```

решает описанную вами проблему...